# How to apply polyline edge grading

Tags: python, cgns

I have a polyline with coordinates and the edge grading for each polyline.How do i apply
the edge grading on the curve.Suppose between point 9 and 13 there are 12 coordinate points
that make the polyline with edge grading of 10.How do i incorporate the edge grading and
make a new polyline.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve. Are [Splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) what you are looking for?

Comment: @JakobS.I am trying to get polylines for a CGNS mesh.Due to non application of edge grading the mesh shape is distorted because edge grading decides which part of the polyline the mesh will be finer and coarser.Now its just points without the proper clustering of points.